# I want to find top 10 favorite trails in laravel queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables named 'favorites' and 'trails'. I want to show top 10 favorites trails for users. I made 'many to many' relationship between them. But, I am not sure how to make the query.What should be the right query.Would someone help me for the right one.  Without relationship, I tried something like this-

```
$favorites = DB::table('favorites')
                                  ->join('trails', 'trails.id', '=', 'favorites.trail_id')
                                  ->select('favorites.trail_id', 'trails.name')
                                  ->get();
```

First one is 'trails' table and another one is 'favorites' bellow -

[image: trails]

[image: favorites]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the top 10 trails you need to use aggregate function to count no of users for each trail and order your results based on the result of count and then select only 10

```
$favorites = DB::table('trails as t')
                ->select('t.id', 't.name')
                ->join('favorites as f', 't.id', '=', 'f.trail_id')
                ->groupBy('t.id')
                ->groupBy('t.name')
                ->orderByRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT f.user_id) DESC')
                ->limit(10)
                ->get();
```

Comment: Its getting query exception

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]:Syntax error or access violation: 1055  'trailboard.t.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `t`.`id`,`t`.`name` from `trails` as `t` inner join `favorites` as `f` on `t`.`id`=`f`.`trail_id` group by `t`.`id` order by COUNT(DISTINCT f.user_id) DESC limit 10)

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan i have updated my answer yes the name was not in group by clause and may be you are running 5.7 or `only_full_group_by` mode is enabled

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I got my expected result.